# Move the menu to the right of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

This code is in the default setting, the list opens to the right, but I want to open this list to the left and move the menu to the right of the page.
When you click on the word file, the menu list gets collated and when you click on the new word, a new list opens. I want to open this new list to the left.
what's the solution?
**The Code:**

```js
var MainMenu = function () {

    var activated = false;

    var settings = {
        disabledClass: 'disabled',
        submenuClass: 'submenu'
    }

    var mask = '<div id="menu-top-mask" style="height: 2px; background-color: #fff; z-index:1001;"/>';
    var timeOut;
    this.init = function (p) {

        $.extend(settings, p);

        $mask = $('#menu-top-mask');

        $('ul.main-menu > li').click(function (event) {
            var target = $(event.target);
            if (target.hasClass(settings.disabledClass) || target.parents().hasClass(settings.disabledClass) || target.hasClass(settings.submenuClass)) {
                return;
            }

            toggleMenuItem($(this));
        });

        $('ul.main-menu > li > ul li').click(function (event) {
   
   // Prevent click event to propagate to parent elements
   event.stopPropagation();

   // Prevent any operations if item is disabled
   if ($(this).hasClass(settings.disabledClass)) {
                return;
            }

            // If item is active, check if there are submenus (ul elements inside current li)
            if ($(this).has( "ul" ).length > 0) {
             // Automatically toggle submenu, if any
                toggleSubMenu($(this));
            }
            else{
             // If there are no submenus, close main menu.
             closeMainMenu();
            }
        });

        $('ul.main-menu > li').mouseenter(function () {
            if (activated && $(this).hasClass('active-menu') == false) {
                toggleMenuItem($(this));
            }
        });

        $('ul.main-menu > li > ul li').mouseenter(function (e) {
            // Hide all other opened submenus in same level of this item
            $el = $(e.target);
            if ($el.hasClass('separator')) return;
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
            var parent = $el.closest('ul');
            parent.find('ul.active-sub-menu').each(function () {
                if ($(this) != $el)
                    $(this).removeClass('active-sub-menu').hide();
            });

            // Show submenu of selected item
            if ($el.children().size() > 0) {
                timeOut = setTimeout(function () { toggleSubMenu($el) }, 500);
            }
        });

        $('ul.main-menu > li > ul li').each(function () {
            if ($(this).children('ul').size() > 0) {
                $(this).addClass(settings.submenuClass);
            }
        });

        $('ul.main-menu li.' + settings.disabledClass).bind('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        //#region - Toggle Main Menu Item -

        toggleMenuItem = function (el) {

            // Hide all open submenus
            $('.active-sub-menu').removeClass('active-sub-menu').hide();

            $('#menu-top-mask').remove();

            var submenu = el.find("ul:first");
            var top = parseInt(el.css('padding-bottom').replace("px", ""), 10) + parseInt(el.css('padding-top').replace("px", ""), 10) +
                        el.position().top +
                        el.height();

            submenu.prepend($(mask));
            var $mask = $('#menu-top-mask');
            var maskWidth = el.width() +
                            parseInt(el.css('padding-left').replace("px", ""), 10) +
                            parseInt(el.css('padding-right').replace("px", ""), 10);

            $mask.css({ position: 'absolute',
                top: '-1px',
                width: (maskWidth) + 'px'
            });

            submenu.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: top + 'px',
                left: el.offset().left + 'px',
                zIndex: 100
            });

            submenu.stop().toggle();
            activated = submenu.is(":hidden") == false;

            !activated ? el.removeClass('active-menu') : el.addClass('active-menu');

            if (activated) {
                $('.active-menu').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).offset().left != el.offset().left) {
                        $(this).removeClass('active-menu');
                        $(this).find("ul:first").hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        //#endregion

        //#region - Toggle Sub Menu Item -

        toggleSubMenu = function (el) {

            if (el.hasClass(settings.disabledClass)) {
                return;
            }

            var submenu = el.find("ul:first");
            var paddingLeft = parseInt(el.css('padding-right').replace('px', ''), 10);
            var borderTop = parseInt(el.css('border-top-width').replace("px", ""), 10);
            borderTop = !isNaN(borderTop) ? borderTop : 1;
            var top = el.position().top - borderTop;

            submenu.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: top + 'px',
                left: el.width() + paddingLeft + 'px',
                zIndex: 1000
            });

            submenu.addClass('active-sub-menu');

            submenu.show();

            //el.mouseleave(function () {
            // submenu.hide();
            //});
        }

        //#endregion

        closeMainMenu = function () {
            activated = false;
            $('.active-menu').find("ul:first").hide();
            $('.active-menu').removeClass('active-menu');
            $('.active-sub-menu').hide();
        };

        $(document).keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                closeMainMenu();
            }
        });

        $(document).bind('click', function (event) {
            var target = $(event.target);
            if (!target.hasClass('active-menu') && !target.parents().hasClass('active-menu')) {
                closeMainMenu();
            }
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    new MainMenu().init();
});
```

```css
#menu-bar
{
}
ul.main-menu
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    padding: 0px;    
}
ul.main-menu > li
{
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 6px 4px 6px 6px;
    line-height: 28px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: default;
    outline: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
    border-color: transparent;
}

ul.main-menu > li.active-menu
{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

ul.main-menu ul li a
{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul.main-menu li ul li a span
{
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #999;
    float:right;
    right: 10px;
    left: auto;
    position: absolute;
}

/* SUBMENU */
ul.main-menu > li  ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
ul.main-menu li ul li
{
    display:list-item;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 26px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    min-width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: 30px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
ul.main-menu a:hover{
 background-color: #ff4718;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
ul.main-menu li:hover
{
    background-color: #ff4718;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
ul.main-menu li.active-menu:hover
{
    background-color: #ff4718;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
ul.main-menu li ul li.disabled, ul.main-menu li ul li.disabled:hover, ul.main-menu li ul li.disabled:hover a
{
    cursor:default;
 background-color: #ff4718;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul.main-menu li.separator  
{
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd; 
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.submenu 
{
    background-image: url(../images/menu-right-arrow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu-bar">
            <ul class="main-menu">
                <li>
                    File
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <li><a href="#">New</a>
                            <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Data</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Storage</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Network</a></li>
                            </ul>
                     </li>
                           
                            </li>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Google search (opens in new tab)</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Document</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Client</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!--<li class="separator"></li>-->
                        <li><a href="#">Save<span>Ctrl+S</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Import</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Print<span>Ctrl+P</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- end mainmenu -->        
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you update this css:

```
#menu-bar {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    display: flex;
}
```

and update this JS:

```
submenu.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: top + 'px',
    left: 'auto',
    right: '0'
    zIndex: 100
});
```

I believe it should do the trick.

Edit: I added right: '0'.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
position: fixed; right: 0; top:0;
}
```